# Junit in atom or sublime

Tags: junit, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I would rather use a lightweight text editor than eclipse (for a few reasons) but I can't seem to figure out how to import the junit JAR into my project without using eclipse. I don't know the java ecosystem very well, what is the best way of achieving this in either editor? or both? Thanks.

I tried putting the junit-4.12 JAR inside my java/jdk/lib/ext folder so that its in the build path of the java compiler, I read somewhere this works, though when I try the following imports I get the error:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

> TTester.java:6: error: package org.junit does not exist
>   import static org.junit.Assert.*;
>                          ^ TTester.java:10: error: package org.junit does not exist import org.junit.Before;
>                   ^TTester.java:11: error: package org.junit does not exist import org.junit.Test;

Answer (score 1):

Using a text editor for a java application is going to be painful.  You could look at some of these packages:

https://atom.io/packages/search?q=java

But I would recommend either Eclipse or IntelliJ Community edition - my personal preference is the latter.  Java development beyond the most simple case really needs a full-blown IDE.